# How to get current working directory of a Xcode Playground?

Tags: macos, swift-playground

I'm using a Playground based on OSX. 
When I tried `NSFileManager.defaultManager().currentDirectoryPath` it returns `/` which is not my working directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "current working directory"? Each process has it's own working directory, and that is what you get from NSFileManager. If that says you are in the root directory then you are.

Comment: it means the full path of my Playground file like `/Users/drinking/workspace/MyPlayground`

Comment: The working directory of your Playground is not the same location as your Playground file itself. Which one do you need, the working dir or the location of the Playground?

Comment: @EricAya OK I mean the location of the Playground

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way I've found (with the help of Zev Eisenberg).

You need a little bit of help.  Add a file to your playground's resources; you can just create a text file by right-clicking "Resources" and choose "New File".  Call it "Token.txt" for the following code to work.

```swift
let tokenPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Token", withExtension: "txt")!.resolvingSymlinksInPath()
let playgroundPath = tokenPath.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent()
```

`playgroundPath` will now be the path of your playground. 
Pretty, eh?

(Tested on Xcode 10 beta 3.)